# vb.net lambda expression problem

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, entityspaces

I am having an strange problem in visual studio 2010, visual basic, and using linq.  My lamda expressions are not showing up in intellesence.  The project I am working on was created in visual studio 2008 and I have converted it to a visual studio 2010 project.

Here is the expression I am trying to run:

```
ClockItemsColl.Filter = ClockItemsColl.AsQueryable().OrderBy(d >= d.Second)
```

However the error I am getting is:

> 'd' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.

I have also tried

```
ClockItemsColl.Filter = ClockItemsColl.AsQueryable().OrderBy(Function(d As ClockItems) d >= d.Second)
```

But is still generates an error and I can't make heads or tails of it.

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'OrderBy' can be called with these arguments:
>       Extension method 'Public Function OrderBy(Of TKey)(keySelector As System.Func(Of BusinessObjects.ClockItems, TKey)) As System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable(Of BusinessObjects.ClockItems)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Operator '>=' is not defined for types 'BusinessObjects.ClockItems' and 'Integer?'.
>       Extension method 'Public Function OrderBy(Of TKey)(keySelector As System.Func(Of BusinessObjects.ClockItems, TKey)) As System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable(Of BusinessObjects.ClockItems)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.
>       Extension method 'Public Function OrderBy(Of TKey)(keySelector As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of BusinessObjects.ClockItems, TKey))) As System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable(Of BusinessObjects.ClockItems)' defined in 'System.Linq.Queryable': Operator '>=' is not defined for types 'BusinessObjects.ClockItems' and 'Integer?'.
>       Extension method 'Public Function OrderBy(Of TKey)(keySelector As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of BusinessObjects.ClockItems, TKey))) As System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable(Of BusinessObjects.ClockItems)' defined in 'System.Linq.Queryable': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.

I am using entityspaces to interface with my datalayer, and this is the first time I am using Linq, so I am going through a bit of growing pains.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is closer to this:

```
ClockItemsColl.Filter = ClockItemsColl.AsQueryable().OrderBy(Function(d) d.Second)
```

[This site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688088.aspx) is a great 'go to' for learning VB linq syntax.

Let me know if anything else comes up.

Comment: That was it, I am not sure exactly why that was it, but it was the answer.  Looks like I have allot of studying to to in Linq.  Marked as answered.